# How to stop doing duplicate code

Tags: c#

I am new to OOP programing and I was wondering whether any one can help me I have been writing some code and I realised that there is a lot of duplications what I need the program to do;

```
class scrape
{
    public void parse()
    {
        string Url = "http://www.blah.co.uk/";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
        Console.WriteLine("URL Loaded,");

        scrape scrape = new scrape();
        scrape.cats(doc);
    }
    private void cats(HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        HtmlNode topcats = doc.GetElementbyId("main_nav");
        if (topcats != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<HtmlNode> topnav = topcats.Descendants("a");
            foreach (var toplink in topnav)
            {
                if (toplink.Attributes.Contains("href"))
                {
                    if (toplink.Attributes["href"].Value.EndsWith(".html"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("http://www.blah.co.uk/" + toplink.Attributes["href"].Value);
                        Console.WriteLine("++++++++ " + toplink.InnerText + " +++++++++++");


                        //sub cats
                        HtmlWeb cat_web = new HtmlWeb();
                        HtmlDocument cat_doc = cat_web.Load("http://www.blah.co.uk/" + toplink.Attributes["href"].Value);

                        HtmlNode subcats = cat_doc.GetElementbyId("pagenav");
                        if (subcats != null)
                        {
                            IEnumerable<HtmlNode> subnav = subcats.Descendants("a");
                            foreach (var sublink in subnav)
                            {
                                if (sublink.Attributes.Contains("href"))
                                {
                                    if (sublink.Attributes["href"].Value.EndsWith(".html"))
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("http://www.blah.co.uk/" +sublink.Attributes["href"].Value);
                                        Console.WriteLine(sublink.InnerText);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

from above could some one please help me to reduce the duplications in code and how I could go about doing this in c#. Any help or information would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: You could use XPath instead of manually traversing the DOM.

Comment: I would reduce the indents as well by inverting the `if` statements, so it's easier to read. i.e. `if (topcats == null) return;` or `if (!toplink.Attributes.Contains("href")) continue;`

Comment: You should post this on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) website

Comment: `how I could go about doing this in c#` It think the site you copied the code from has forgotten to mention the language. It is already in `c#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your questing is really about introduction to OOP.
When designing a OOP application, you need to think what are you doing, 
what are the "things" that are participating, divide them to classes and to objects (instances of the class). 
think what can a object do and write the most basic actions, then make more complex actions based on the basic ones.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5kfCH50wl0

For example of instancing and creation, the Parse method is a part of the object, and it creates a new instance for no reason that can be seen.

I have made a devision to methods for you.

```
public void Read()
{
     HtmlDocument topDocument = LoadDocument("blah.uk");
     IEnumerable<HtmlNode> topLinks = ReadLinks(topDocument, "main_nav");
     foreach (HtmlNode topLink in topLinks) {
         HtmlDocument catDoc = LoadDocument("littletreasurespartybags" + toplink.Attributes["href"].Value);
         IEnumerable<HtmlNode> catLinks = ReadLinks(topDocument, "main_nav");
         foreach (HtmlNode catLink in catLinks) {
             .....
         }
     }
}

private HtmlDocument LoadDocument(string Url) { ..... }
private IEnumerable<HtmlNode> ReadLinks(HtmlDocument document, string topElement) { ....}
```